ServicesApiController route returns 403 on CD but not on CM
On my Sitecore 10.2.1 site, when making a request to my custom route, cd.acme.com/api/MyController/MyMethod, I am getting a 403 response code with a response body of You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
I also see a WARN in my CD log that says:
[Sitecore Services]: Unauthorized request (originated from IP : MY_IP_ADDRESS) for ACME.Feature.MyFeature.Controllers.MyController 
The log is being triggered by the identity sitecore\ServicesAPI using the logger
Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Diagnostics.SitecoreLogger.
My controller inherits from ServicesApiController, and my method has a [HttpGet] attribute.
This route does not require any kind of authentication that I am aware of. I can get a successful response from this same route on my CM without any authentication.
Why might this be happening?

Thanks in part to @ckhanna's answer, it was discovered that CD is actually exhibiting the expected default behavior of blocking the request, given that CD uses the default ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, which denies access to all Entity and ItemServices from requests originating from remote clients.
The reason why the request works on CM is because there happened to be a patch config related to Horizon (introduced in Sitecore 10.0 but deprecated in 10.3) which sets the SecurityPolicy setting to ServicesOnPolicy (thus allowing access to all Entity and ItemServices):
<setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" patch:source="Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.SSC.config"/>

That said, the default Sitecore config ships with an AnonymousUserFilter which prevents unauthorized users from accessing the Sitecore Services Client (SSC) endpoints:
<filter desc="AnonymousUserFilter">Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Filters.AnonymousUserFilter, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure</filter>

I tested one of the default SSC endpoints by pinging cm.acme.com/sitecore/api/ssc/item?path=/sitecore/content. It returned a 403 response unless I was authenticated.
However, the custom controller that inherited from ServicesApiController did not appear to apply the AnonymousUserFilter filter (presumably, such filters would need to be applied explicitly).
Takeaway: if you are using ServicesApiController, make sure that the accessibility of the routes align with what you expect across your various environments / roles.

Although the other answers work just fine, enabling all remote requests seems risky. I still want Sitecore to prevent any remote attempts to other parts of the site.
According to Sitecore documentation you can exclude specific controllers from these security policies.
You can do this by adding your controller to the allowedControllers node of the Sitecore.Services.Client.config.

Yes, and if using SXA this can also be configured via configuration items in the Content Editor.

Since Sitecore Service API inherits from Sitecore Service Controller, by default following ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy is enabled which denies access to all Entity and ItemServices from requests originating from remote clients.
Configuration for the security policy is defined as below.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <!--  SITECORE SERVICES SECURITY POLICY
                  Specifies the Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.IAuthorizePolicy derived type that will set the security policy
                  for the Sitecore services.

                  Policies:

                  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOffPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
                  - Policy denies access to all Entity and Item Services

                  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
                  - Policy denies access to all Entity and Item Services from requests originating from remote clients

                  Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
                  - Policy allows access to all Entity and Item Services

                  Default: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure
            -->
            <setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesLocalOnlyPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

You can find more details on the security policy here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any questions.
